# JS: cant stop setInterval with clearInterval

Tags: javascript, button, setinterval, clearinterval

Hello there: i strike once again with a problem.

I created function that makes button work like, eh, tumbler. But i cant find a way to stop setInterval with clearInterval from another button state.

```
function goIdle(checker)
{
if(checker===1){
buttonDeeper.disabled=true;
var intIdle=(setInterval(goDeeperTest, 2000));//(600000-(bootTier*600)));
buttonIdle.value='Остановиться';
buttonIdle.addEventListener('click', function() {goIdle(2)}, false);
}
if (checker===2) {
clearInterval(intIdle);
buttonDeeper.disabled = false;
buttonIdle.value='Разбежаться';
buttonIdle.addEventListener('click', function() {goIdle(1)}, false);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `intIdle` variable is local to one execution of your `goIdle` function. Declare it in the outer scope so that it is kept between function executions :

```
var intIdle;
function goIdle(checker)
{
if(checker===1){
buttonDeeper.disabled=true;
intIdle=(setInterval(goDeeperTest, 2000));//(600000-(bootTier*600)));
buttonIdle.value='Остановиться';
buttonIdle.addEventListener('click', function() {goIdle(2)}, false);
}
if (checker===2) {
clearInterval(intIdle);
buttonDeeper.disabled = false;
buttonIdle.value='Разбежаться';
buttonIdle.addEventListener('click', function() {goIdle(1)}, false);

}
```

But Another problem you have is that you never seem to remove the event listeners. So at each click, you call one more of them. It can't work. What you really seem to want is

```
buttonIdle.addEventListener('click', goIdle, false);
var intIdle;
function goIdle() {
    if (intIdle) {
        clearInterval(intIdle);
        buttonIdle.value='Разбежаться';
        buttonDeeper.disabled = false;
        intIdle = 0;
    } else {
        intIdle=setInterval(goDeeperTest, 2000);
        buttonDeeper.disabled = true;
        buttonIdle.value='Остановиться';
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it. After clicking on buttonIdle SetInterval still works.

Comment: Another problem you may add is that you never seem to remove the event listeners. So at each click, you call one more of them. It can't work.

Comment: @ArtemSuchkov I edited to fix that (supposing I understand what you try to do).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
buttonIdle.addEventListener('click', function() {goIdle(2)}, false);
```

use

```
buttonIdle.onclick = function() {goIdle(2)}, false);
```

otherwise your button keeps having 2 listeners.